# Issue in loading dataframes in multiple sheets of Excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

My code is returning multiple dataframes and I want these dataframes to be exported to multiple sheets of single excel file. I researched and found that it can be implemented using ExcelWriter. However, when I am running this code only my first dataframe is getting exported into excel file and rest dataframes are not going into excel.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for k in l:   
    with udaExec.connect(method="odbc",system=host, username=username,password=password, driver="Teradata") as connect:
        QP = pd.read_sql_query(k,connect)

    with udaExec.connect(method="odbc",system=host1, username=username1,password=password1, driver="Teradata") as connect:
        QD= pd.read_sql_query(k,connect)

    Final_result = pd.merge(QP,QD,on='ID', how='outer', indicator = True)

    cnt = cnt+1    
    sh = f'''she_{cnt}'''
    print(sh)

    Final_result.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = sh)    
    writer.save()
```

I want multiple dataframes to be exported to multiple sheets of excel.

Comment: You need to move the save() out of the loop.

Comment: @jmcnamara: Thanks a lot :) It worked. You can put this comment as answer if you want, I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the `save()` outside of the loop.